# Exchange 2007 SCR Setup Error finding Domain Controller?

Tags: exchange, domain, domain-controller

just setting up my SCR enviroment however when running the Enable-StorageGroupCopy command its returning with an error stating that my exchange server object could not be found on my domain controller.

any ideas as to why it would state this ? Both the live server and DR server are in the domain and all client PC's are able to send and receive email through the live server. You can view this server and even manage it from AD so i'm unsure why i'm receiving this error message. any help would be great

Thanks

Nathan

here is the error i'm receiving - EXSRV01 is the live server and EXSRV02 is the Standby and FSG is the storage group i want to copy over

```
     Welcome to the Exchange Management Shell!
```

Full list of cmdlets:          get-command
 Only Exchange cmdlets:         get-excommand
 Cmdlets for a specific role:   get-help -role *UM* or *Mailbox*
 Get general help:              help
 Get help for a cmdlet:         help  or  -?
 Show quick reference guide:    quickref
 Exchange team blog:            get-exblog
 Show full output for a cmd:     | format-list

Tip of the day #31:

Do you love the Exchange Management Shell's Tip of the Day? Try this out:

Get-Tip

[PS] C:\Windows\system32>enable-storagegroupcopy -identity fsg -standbymachine e
xsrv02
Enable-StorageGroupCopy : The operation could not be performed because object '
fsg' could not be found on domain controller 'dc003.network.com'.
At line:1 char:24
+ enable-storagegroupcopy <<<<  -identity fsg -standbymachine exsrv02
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (0:Int32) [Enable-StorageGroupCopy
   ], ManagementObjectNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FEF7F95C,Microsoft.Exchange.Management.SystemCon
   figurationTasks.EnableStorageGroupCopy

[PS] C:\Windows\system32>

Comment: Are you setting up a _new_ Exchange 2007 deployment? Are you aware of the support lifecycle?

Comment: not a new exchange 2007 SETUP. this is a secondary server to allow us to have SCR . dont worry i've managed to resolve the above issue now